# Iterate through Map in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, nunjucks

I am trying to iterate through a Map object in HTML using for loop.

```
{%for s in objects%}
   <a>{{s}}</a>
{%endfor%}
```

The object is a Map (i.e. {a: b, c: d, e: f})
When I run this code, {{s}} will give me the value of the the object (i.e. b, d, f).
**How do I get the Key of this object?**

Comment: probably `Object.keys`

Comment: It doesn't work. Also tried .key,  .getKey(), .getKey

Comment: `for (let [key, value] of yourMap)`?

Comment: Also I have no clue what `{%for s in objects%}` is since that ain;t JavaScript and HTML

Comment: @Kaiido where should I put the for loop in this case? Because putting it inside the {} doesn't work

Comment: @epascarello I honestly don't know what embedded language is this. I got it from a tutorial. Do you know any other way to iterate in HTML?

Comment: You can't iterate **anything** in HTML. It is a declarative language only, its one function is to describe the contents of a document. Javascript is used to add client-side functionality to web pages. What you have there is not pure javascript, it is some other framework or engine. Perhaps provide the link to the tutorial you got this from.

Comment: @FeliciaAmy HTML isn't a programming language. You can't perform computations with HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this written in a templating engine? I think it looks like Nunjucks code.T

This is from the Nunjucks homepage

```
<ul>
  {% for name, item in items %}
  <li>{{ name }}: {{ item }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: Yea no problem, @FeliciaAmy -- you might look into extending nunjucks. I don't know it that well, but handlebars and other similar templating engines allow for you to create helper methods. I'm sure nunjucks is no different. You won't get far with it unless you learn to write your own helper methods too

Comment: Yes I'll take a look at it. Thanks :)